# What is "application/gas-events-abn" object in Wordpress editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress to create a blog and I noticed that when I save a post multiple times, a weird element appears in the code, creating a big white space in the bottom of the post.

The code looks like this:

```
...post content

&nbsp;

<object id="ba7ab859-2a8a-9fa1-988a-4a9938aba59b" width="0" height="0" type="application/gas-events-abn"></object>
```

Every time I edit a post I have to remove it. With Joomla sometimes used to happen the same thing. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 23):

This tag is added by protection bank plugin developed by Gas Tecnologia, a brazilian company, expert in internet security. This company provides service to the banks: Banco do Brasil, Caixa Econômica Federal, Itaú, Santander, Banco Mercantil do Brasil, Banco da Amazônia, Banestes, Tecnocred/Unicred.

I contacted the company to find out why the "tag object", but so far not replied.

If you wish this is the link to site of company: http://www.gastecnologia.com.br

Comment: I can't believe those a**holes, besides creating plugins that barely work and block us from using our banks, are also breaking our sites styles!

Answer (score 14):

As [said by Vinicius Monteiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20399748/102960), this is a serious bug from the [crazy devs on Gas Tecnologia](http://www.gastecnologia.com.br). The hack-ish way we're using to solve this is adding this piece of CSS to your pages: 
`object[type^=application/gas-events] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 3):

I did some adjust to hide all elements with contains the word **application/gas-events**:

```
object[type*='application/gas-events'] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your site (or browser) has been hacked. You can find the same string with varying id in some forums:

- [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5b815f6d-8627-4a36-ba0c-b8a64eaa0e0c)
- [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/projectprofessional2010general/thread/7e4bd0bf-789e-45dd-90b8-969d120d7773)
- [answers.atlassian.com](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/178202/manage-jira-license)
- [forum.dancehallreggae.com](http://forum.dancehallreggae.com/archive/index.php/t-245098.html)
- [many more](https://www.google.de/#q=%22application%2Fgas-events-abn%22).

### Other findings

Most of the affected sites are Brasilian.

According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/delta2kbr/status/331936117450502144), the tag is generated by a *Santander protection module*.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing with "GBBD Caixa Economica Federal" extension (Chrome), putting this "application/gas-events-abn" everywhere. Seems to be a common problem with intern banking extensions.

And to get worst it's impossible to deactivate while not using internet banking (at least in Chrome), the only solution is remove the extension or clean the post content field AND the excerpt field if it have tinymce activated.

Answer (score 1):

```
body + object, body + object + object { display: none; }
```

I placed that on my Stilysh Chrome Extension and solved the problem just fine since they put the objects always in the footer (in my case there where 2 of them, CEF (caixa economica federal) and BB (banco do brasil) if you have more banks, just add more objects ;)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the class object had height 100%. I just commented the code.

```
object, embed{
    /* height:100& */ I commented this height, because it leaves a space under the footer;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, passe para ingles a sua resposta. Caso queira escrever em portugues, utiliza o orum dedicado par aportugues: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: object "class"? what does your code have to do with the original question? I didn't get it. Furthermore, there's a better solution in my own answer already.