# Inivisible margin bottom on chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website and right at the beggining I noticed a weird margin at the bottom. This only happens on google chrome (current version: 48.0.2564.97).

The only `css` I'm using is the normalize.css and the css I'm showing below, also the `html` is very simple, with just the index and a `div` `with:100vh`.

Note, on firefox there isn't this margin, only on chrome. See image (left: firefox, right: chrome):
[image]

While inspecting the element on chrome, the html tag is the only one extending with that extra margin included. Both, body and div, end with the blue box.

html:

```
//...
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
html {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.login {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #cde;
}
```

---

#### Edit:

By setting `margin-bottom: -20px;` on the body, the problem is solved. But i'd like to understand better what is happening, since there is nothing else creating that gap.

Comment: It worked fine for  me..:|

Comment: This may be the same problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20399748/2458234

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.login {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #cde;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this an answer / doubt / explanation /query ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add *height: 100%* to the **body, html** and remove *height: 100vh* from your **.login**, its going to work :)

Comment: Same result.. The problem with body:100% is when there is more content. It has some weird behavior in some cases. I Tried using min-height:100%; but also no difference.

Comment: hmmm.. did you applied height: 100% to body and **html**? and removed the height: 100vh from login?

Comment: Yes. Tried both solutions, also with !important, but no difference. The only difference is that the .login didn't filled the page, which is how it's supposed to be. But just a design decision.

Comment: My last tip: add height: 100% to body and html and then add height: 100% to login too

Comment: Also tried that.. The weird thing is that there is no element showing.. According to the inspect, the 'Space' is between the html and body tag. The body tag is correct at 100% (or vh). But the html has this 20px more (doesn't matter how hight is the window... The space is always the same, it isn't variable. If I resize the window, the space has the same height.

Comment: I used that example to test and it worked with me. You should try to disable the normalize and see if it works without it and check if its everything alright in your html.

Comment: Windows 10 + Chrome 48